# BNLearn Bayesian Networks - how is the structure decided?

Tags: python, bayesian-network, bnlearn

I'm currently playing around with BNLearn on Python, and creating BN's from Pandas datasets. I'm not really sure why/how the package decides on the structure of the BNs it creates; see for example this BN generated from the Titanic dataset:

[image]

I got the above from an example on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/vbmokin/titanic-predict-using-a-simple-bayesian-network), with the relevant code being

```py
# Structure learning
DAG = bn.structure_learning.fit(dfnum, methodtype='hc', root_node='Survived', bw_list_method='nodes', verbose=3)

# Plot
G = bn.plot(DAG)

# Parameter learning
model = bn.parameter_learning.fit(DAG, dfnum, verbose=3);
```

I would have thought that *all* variables affect `Survived` (ie more being a Naive Bayes classifier than a full on BN here). How has this structure been generated, and what difference does this make (in terms of accuracy and applicability) from Naive Bayes?

Comment: How can we know how this Bayesian network was generated when we don't know anything but the fact that you used `bnlearn`? It can do many things: [bnlearn’s documentation](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/index.html).

Comment: @dipetkov my apologies - I've updated the OP, I hope it's more clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [`bnlearn`](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/index.html) "only" learns [*Bayesian networks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network), so the arrows cannot be interpreted as causal directions. The [documentation](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/Structure%20learning.html#) claims that causality "is incorporated in Bayesian graphical models" but that is only true for *causal* Bayesian graphical models. Bayesian networks are mainly used to describe stochastic dependencies and contain only limited causal information. E.g., if you give a dataset of two dependent binary variables $X$ and $Y$ to `bnlearn`, it will either return $X\to Y$ or $Y\to X$ independent of whether $X$ caused $Y$ or $Y$ caused $X$, **because the causal relation cannot be deduced just from the observations of $X$ and $Y$**.

Thus, if you say "I would have thought that all variables affect Survived", referring to the direction of the arrows, then this insinuates that you presume the arrows to indicate causal effect, which is not the case.

Now to your question: "How has this structure been generated?" You have used the method [Hillclimbing](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/Structure%20learning.html#hillclimbsearch) which is a **greedy** local method, i.e. it is fast but can lead to wrong results.

Next, the [NaiveBayes](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn/pages/html/Structure%20learning.html#naivebayes) method: First, note that the documentation says: "Naive Bayes is a special case of Bayesian Model where the only edges in the model are from the feature variables to the dependent variable." If this was true, conditioning on the dependent variable would make all the features dependent. However, the defining property of Naive Bayes is that it is actually the other way around: conditioning on the dependent variable makes all the features *independent*.

**Summary**:

- If you are interested in causation, don't use `bnlearn`, but causality software, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_causal_analysis#Software_Packages), [here](https://py-why.github.io/dowhy/v0.8/), or [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/CausalInference.html).
- If you are (only) interested in the probabilistic graphical models described by Bayesian networks, then I would rather suggest trying something more trustworthy like the R package [`bnlearn`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/index.html) and [friends](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/GraphicalModels.html).

Comment: Thank you for replying! That was a really thoughtful answer, and really helpful, so thank you so much for taking the time to write that out. I thought the R version of `bnlearn` was the same as the Python one - is that not the case? If not, is the R version significantly better then?

Comment: Please mention any issues or feature requests regarding Python's `bnlearn` [here](https://github.com/erdogant/bnlearn/issues).